# What is the version of @component (from .blade) for twig file?

Tags: twig, laravel-blade

I don't know if this is right version of **@component** for twig? Is it **render**?

```
{{ render ('mail::message') }}
{{ render ('mail::button', ['url' => '']) }}
```

or maybe I am not able to write the right syntax here?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Twig's [`macro`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html).

For the Blade

```html
<!-- /resources/views/demo.blade.php -->

{{ $slot }}
```

```html
<!-- component use -->

@component('demo')
    content
@endcomponent
```

the basic Twig syntax would be

```html
{# macro definition #}

{% macro demo(param) %}
    {{ param }}
{% endmacro %}
```

```html
{# macro use #}

{# first import and then you can #}
{{ demo('content') }}
```

You'll need to import the macro before calling it, either with [`from`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/from.html) or [`import`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/import.html). To import (with either `from` or `import`) from the current file, use `_self` instead of a path. See the docs for more explanation

---

Your example

```html
{{ render ('mail::button', ['url' => '']) }}
```

looks like it's coming from Blade's `@include`, something like

```html
@include('mail::button, ['url' => ''])
```

For that, Twig's [`include`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html) might be a better fit. The relationship between `macro`s and `include`s in Twig is similar to the relationship between `component`s and `include`s in Blade. The basic Twig would be

```html
{# partial.html #}

{{ url }}
```

```html
{# partial use #}

{% include 'partial.html' with {url: ''} %}
```